# Number of heads streaks across $16$ coin tosses with unfair coin

Tags: probability, expected-value, markov-chains

Here is a question I am trying to solve:

> An unfair coin with probability $p$ for head is thrown $16$ times in a row. Find the expectation of the number of streaks of heads.

**My thoughts:** The result of the sequence number of streaks of heads with length $n$ is $(n-1)(1-p)p + p$.

Starting from the second throw, the probability that it starts a new H streak is $P(\text{previously T})P(\text{now H}) = (1-p)p$, using linearity of expectation it is $(n-1)(1-p)p$; plus the first coin is $p$ contributed by H.

Nonetheless I'm not sure how to finish. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why you need $n$ here.  All you want is the number of heads which were not immediately preceded by a tails.

Comment: @lulu: Did you intend to say "the expected number of heads which were not immediately preceded by a *heads*"?   That would lead me to the expectation calculation and result in the question, which I think  is correct (though you can replace $n$ by $16$).  It is certainly correct when $n=1$ giving $p$ and when $n=2$ giving  $2p-p^2$.

Comment: @Henry  Absolutely.